# Linear feedback shift register?

Tags: python, language-agnostic, digital-logic

Lately I bumped repeatedly into the concept of LFSR, that I find quite interesting because of its links with different fields and also fascinating in itself. It took me some effort to understand, the final help was this really good [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120616135434/http://homepage.mac.com:80/afj/lfsr.html), much better than the (at first) cryptic [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). So I wanted to write some small code for a program that worked like a LFSR. To be more precise, that somehow showed how a LFSR works. Here's the cleanest thing I could come up with after some lenghtier attempts (Python):

```
def lfsr(seed, taps):
    sr, xor = seed, 0
    while 1:
        for t in taps:
            xor += int(sr[t-1])
        if xor%2 == 0.0:
            xor = 0
        else:
            xor = 1
        print(xor)
        sr, xor = str(xor) + sr[:-1], 0
        print(sr)
        if sr == seed:
            break

lfsr('11001001', (8,7,6,1))      #example
```

I named "xor" the output of the XOR function, not very correct.
However, this is just meant to show how it circles through its possible states, in fact you noticed the register is represented by a string. Not much logical coherence.

This can be easily turned into a nice toy you can watch for hours (at least I could :-)

```
def lfsr(seed, taps):
    import time
    sr, xor = seed, 0
    while 1:
        for t in taps:
            xor += int(sr[t-1])
        if xor%2 == 0.0:
            xor = 0
        else:
            xor = 1
        print(xor)
        print('')
        time.sleep(0.75)
        sr, xor = str(xor) + sr[:-1], 0
        print(sr)
        print('')
        time.sleep(0.75)
```

Then it struck me, what use is this in writing software? I heard it can generate random numbers; is it true? how?
So, it would be nice if someone could:

- explain how to use such a device in software development
- come up with some code, to support the point above or just like mine to show different ways to do it, in any language

Also, as theres not much didactic stuff around about this piece of logic and digital circuitry, it would be nice if this could be a place for noobies (like me) to get a better understanding of this *thing*, or better, to understand what it is and how it can be useful when writing software. Should have made it a community wiki?

That said, if someone feels like golfing... you're welcome.

Comment: If you search for lfsr in SO you will find a lot ...

Comment: I did, not so much what I wanted

Comment: Why is this tagged as code-golf?

Comment: @Landei: because I would have (also) liked to see it golfed. if that's not enough for the tag, sorry.

Comment: just 2 days ago I used LFSR to transform an integer sequence to a semi-random one and then convert it back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804100/how-to-design-a-sequential-hash-like-function/9848014#9848014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, algorithms based on LFSR are very common. CRC is actually directly based on LFSR. Of course, in computer science classes people talk about polynomials when they're talking about how the input value is supposed to be XORed with the accumulated value, in electornics engineering we talk about taps instead. They are the same just different terminology.

CRC32 is a very common one. It's used to detect errors in Ethernet frames. That means that when I posted this answer my PC used an LFSR based algorithm to generate a hash of the IP packet so that my router can verify that what it's transmitting isn't corrupted.

Zip and Gzip files are another example. Both use CRC for error detection. Zip uses CRC32 and Gzip uses both CRC16 and CRC32.

CRCs are basically hash functions. And it's good enough to make the internet work. Which means LFSRs are fairly good hash functions. I'm not sure if you know this but in general good hash functions are considered good random number generators. But the thing with LFSR is that selecting the correct taps (polynomials) is very important to the quality of the hash/random number.

Your code is generally toy code since it operates on a string of ones and zeros. In the real world LFSR work on bits in a byte. Each byte you push through the LFSR changes the accumulated value of the register. That value is effectively a checksum of all the bytes you've push through the register. Two common ways of using that value as a random number is to either use a counter and push a sequence of numbers through the register, thereby transforming the linear sequence 1,2,3,4 to some hashed sequence like 15306,22,5587,994, or to feed back the current value into the register to generate a new number in seemingly random sequence.

It should be noted that doing this naively using bit-fiddling LFSR is quite slow since you have to process bits at a time. So people have come up with ways using pre-calculated tables to do it eight bits at a time or even 32 bits at a time. This is why you almost never see LFSR code in the wild. In most production code it masquerades as something else.

But sometimes a plain bit-twiddling LFSR can come in handy. I once wrote a [Modbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) driver for a PIC micro and that protocol used CRC16. A pre-calculated table requires 256 bytes of memory and my CPU only had 68 bytes ([I'm not kidding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC16x84)). So I had to use an LFSR.

Comment: TCP/IP uses a simple checksum, not CRC32. Other protocols may have additional means of detecting errors (e.g: Ethernet has a FCS which IIRC is a CRC).

Comment: @ninjalj: Corrected. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 15):

Since I was looking for a LFSR-implementation in Python, I stumbled upon this topic. I found however that the following was a bit more accurate according to my needs:

```py
def lfsr(seed, mask):
    result = seed
    nbits = mask.bit_length()-1
    while True:
        result = (result << 1)
        xor = result >> nbits
        if xor != 0:
            result ^= mask

        yield xor, result
```

The above LFSR-generator is based on GF(2<sup>k</sup>) modulus calculus (GF = [Galois Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)). Having just completed an Algebra course, I'm going to explain this the mathematical way.

Let's start by taking, for example, GF(2<sup>4</sup>), which equals to {a<sub>4</sub>x<sup>4</sup> + a<sub>3</sub>x<sup>3</sup> + a<sub>2</sub>x<sup>2</sup> + a<sub>1</sub>x<sup>1</sup> + a<sub>0</sub>x<sup>0</sup> | a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>4</sub> ∈ Z<sub>2</sub>} (to clarify, Z<sub>n</sub> = {0,1,...,n-1} and therefore Z<sub>2</sub> = {0,1}, i.e. one bit). This means that this is the set of all polynomials of the fourth degree with all factors either being present or not, but having no multiples of these factors (e.g. there's no 2x<sup>k</sup>). x<sup>3</sup>, x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup>, 1 and x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1 are all examples of members of this group.

We take this set modulus a polynomial of the fourth degree (i.e., P(x) ∈ GF(2<sup>4</sup>)), e.g. P(x) = x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>1</sup>+x<sup>0</sup>. This modulus operation on a group is also denoted as GF(2<sup>4</sup>) / P(x). For your reference, P(x) describes the 'taps' within the LFSR.

We also take a random polynomial of degree 3 or lower (so that it's not affected by our modulus, otherwise we could just as well perform the modulus operation directly on it), e.g. A<sub>0</sub>(x) = x<sup>0</sup>. Now every subsequent A<sub>i</sub>(x) is calculated by multiplying it with x: A<sub>i</sub>(x) = A<sub>i-1</sub>(x) * x mod P(x).

Since we are in a limited field, the modulus operation may have an effect, but only when the resulting A<sub>i</sub>(x) has at least a factor x<sup>4</sup> (our highest factor in P(x)). Note that, since we are working with numbers in Z<sub>2</sub>, performing the modulus operation itself is nothing more than determining whether every a<sub>i</sub> becomes a 0 or 1 by adding the two values from P(x) and A<sub>i</sub>(x) together (i.e., 0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+1=0, or 'xoring' these two).

Every polynomial can be written as a set of bits, for example x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>1</sup>+x<sup>0</sup> ~ 10011. The A<sub>0</sub>(x) can be seen as the seed. The 'times x' operation can be seen as a shift left operation. The modulus operation can be seen as a bit masking operation, with the mask being our P(x).

The algorithm depicted above therefore generates (an infinite stream of) valid four bit LFSR patterns. For example, for our defined A<sub>0</sub>(x) *(x<sup>0</sup>)* and P(x) *(x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>1</sup>+x<sup>0</sup>)*, we can define the following first yielded results in GF(2<sup>4</sup>) (note that A<sub>0</sub> is not yielded until at the end of the first round -- mathematicians generally start counting at '1'):

```
 i   Ai(x)                   'x⁴'  bit pattern
 0   0x³ + 0x² + 0x¹ + 1x⁰   0     0001        (not yielded)
 1   0x³ + 0x² + 1x¹ + 0x⁰   0     0010
 2   0x³ + 1x² + 0x¹ + 0x⁰   0     0100
 3   1x³ + 0x² + 0x¹ + 0x⁰   0     1000
 4   0x³ + 0x² + 1x¹ + 1x⁰   1     0011        (first time we 'overflow')
 5   0x³ + 1x² + 1x¹ + 0x⁰   0     0110
 6   1x³ + 1x² + 0x¹ + 0x⁰   0     1100
 7   1x³ + 0x² + 1x¹ + 1x⁰   1     1011
 8   0x³ + 1x² + 0x¹ + 1x⁰   1     0101
 9   1x³ + 0x² + 1x¹ + 0x⁰   0     1010
10   0x³ + 1x² + 1x¹ + 1x⁰   1     0111
11   1x³ + 1x² + 1x¹ + 0x⁰   0     1110
12   1x³ + 1x² + 1x¹ + 1x⁰   1     1111
13   1x³ + 1x² + 0x¹ + 1x⁰   1     1101
14   1x³ + 0x² + 0x¹ + 1x⁰   1     1001
15   0x³ + 0x² + 0x¹ + 1x⁰   1     0001        (same as i=0)
```

Note that your mask must contain a '1' at the fourth position to make sure that your LFSR generates four-bit results. Also note that a '1' must be present at the zeroth position to make sure that your bitstream would not end up with a 0000 bit pattern, or that the final bit would become unused (if all bits are shifted to the left, you would also end up with a zero at the 0th position after one shift).

Not all P(x)'s necessarily are generators for GF(2<sup>k</sup>) (i.e., not all masks of k bits generate all 2<sup>k-1</sup>-1 numbers). For example, x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>1</sup> + x<sup>0</sup> generates 3 groups of 5 distinct polynomals each, or "3 cycles of period 5": 0001,0010,0100,1000,1111; 0011,0110,1100,0111,1110; and 0101,1010,1011,1001,1101. Note that 0000 can never be generated, and can't generate any other number.

Usually, the output of an LFSR is the bit that is 'shifted' out, which is a '1' if the modulus operation is performed, and a '0' when it isn't. LFSR's with a period of 2<sup>k-1</sup>-1, also called pseudo-noise or PN-LFSR's, adhere to Golomb's randomness postulates, which says as much as that this output bit is random 'enough'.

Sequences of these bits therefore have their use in cryptography, for instance in the A5/1 and A5/2 mobile encryption standards, or the E0 Bluetooth standard. However, they are not as secure as one would like: the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm) can be used to reverse-engineer the characteristic polynomal (the P(x)) of the LFSR. Strong encryption standards therefore use [Non-linear FSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLFSR)'s or similar non-linear functions. A related topic to this are the [S-Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) used in AES.

---

*Note that I have used the [`int.bit_length()` operation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length). This was not implemented until Python 2.7.

If you'd only like a finite bit pattern, you could check whether the seed equals the result and then break your loop.

You can use my LFSR-method in a for-loop (e.g. `for xor, pattern in lfsr(0b001,0b10011)`) or you can repeatedly call the `.next()` operation on the result of the method, returning a new `(xor, result)`-pair everytime.*

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications of LFSRs. One of them is generating noise, for instance the SN76489 and variants (used on the Master System, Game Gear, MegaDrive, NeoGeo Pocket, ...) use a LFSR to generate white/periodic noise. There's a really good description of SN76489's LFSR [in this page](http://www.smspower.org/Development/SN76489?sid=891c9fb2f808cfdd1e1d12416f9bccf8#NoiseChannel).

Comment: i recently had to write some software that calibrates seismic detectors.  it turns out that at least one company (nanometrics) uses LFSRs to generate a "noise" signal used to measure frequency response (you feed this noise to the detectors, measure the response, and then compare the FFT of the response with the FFT of the input; that gives you the response of the system to a range of frequencies).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of my python libraries - [pylfsr](https://github.com/Nikeshbajaj/Linear_Feedback_Shift_Register) to implement LFSR. I have tried to make it an efficient that can handle any length of LFSR  to generate the binary sequence.

```
import numpy as np
from pylfsr import LFSR

#for 5-bit LFSR with polynomial  x^5 + x^4 +  x^3 + x^2 +1
seed = [0,0,0,1,0]
fpoly = [5,4,3,2]
L = LFSR(fpoly=fpoly,initstate =seed)
seq = L.runKCycle(10)
```

You can display all the info at step too,

```
state = [1,1,1]
fpoly = [3,2]
L = LFSR(initstate=state,fpoly=fpoly,counter_start_zero=False)
print('count \t state \t\toutbit \t seq')
print('-'*50)
for _ in range(15):
    print(L.count,L.state,'',L.outbit,L.seq,sep='\t')
    L.next()
print('-'*50)
print('Output: ',L.seq)
```

Output

```
count    state      outbit   seq
--------------------------------------------------
1   [1 1 1]     1   [1]
2   [0 1 1]     1   [1 1]
3   [0 0 1]     1   [1 1 1]
4   [1 0 0]     0   [1 1 1 0]
5   [0 1 0]     0   [1 1 1 0 0]
6   [1 0 1]     1   [1 1 1 0 0 1]
7   [1 1 0]     0   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
8   [1 1 1]     1   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
9   [0 1 1]     1   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
10  [0 0 1]     1   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
11  [1 0 0]     0   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]
12  [0 1 0]     0   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
13  [1 0 1]     1   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1]
14  [1 1 0]     0   [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0]
--------------------------------------------------
Output:  [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```

Also can be visualize like this

[image]

**Check out the [Documentation here](https://lfsr.readthedocs.io/)**

Comment: how did you visualize this? was it matplotlib or something else?

Comment: Yes, visulization is done using matplotlib. Here is a simple way to visualize it:

`from pylfsr import LFSR

L = LFSR(initstate=[1,1,0,1,1],fpoly=[5,2])
L.runKCycle(15)
L.Viz(title='R1')
`
Here is a link to full documentation:
https://pylfsr.github.io/viz/index.html

Comment: Just adding to inform, much simpler way to visualize LFSR: ```pylfsr.dispLFSR(state=[1,1,1,1,1],fpoly=[5,2],conf='fibonacci', seq='',ob=1,fb=0,out_bit_index=-1)```. This is again in pylfsr library

Answer (score 1):

To make it really elegant and Pythonic, try to create a generator, `yield`-ing successive values from the LFSR. Also, comparing to a floating point `0.0` is unnecessary and confusing.

A LFSR is just one of many ways to create pseudo-random numbers in computers. Pseudo-random, because there numbers aren't *really* random - you can easily repeat them by starting with the seed (initial value) and proceeding with the same mathematical operations.

Comment: I'll try, though right now I'm not sure how to do that. I thought the 0.0 would allow me to avoid another expression... in fact you're right, its useless. So it generates a number for each state, I mean, the states are the numbers it generates? does it have other uses?

Comment: @Mattia: did you see the "applications" section on Wikipedia - looks quite full of information

Comment: its good, still its focus is more towards hardware applications, and I also would have liked to see some code with it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a variation on your code using integers and binary operators instead of strings. It also uses yield as someone suggested.

```
def lfsr2(seed, taps):
    sr = seed
    nbits = 8
    while 1:
        xor = 1
        for t in taps:
            if (sr & (1<<(t-1))) != 0:
                xor ^= 1
        sr = (xor << nbits-1) + (sr >> 1)
        yield xor, sr
        if sr == seed:
            break

nbits = 8
for xor, sr in lfsr2(0b11001001, (8,7,6,1)):
    print xor, bin(2**nbits+sr)[3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a piece of code where you can choose your seed, the number of bits and the taps you want:

```
from functools import reduce 

def lfsr(seed=1, bits=8, taps=[8, 6, 5, 4]):
    """
            1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (bits == 8)
           ┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
        ┌─→│0│1│0│1│0│0│1│1├─→
        │  └─┴─┴─┴┬┴┬┴─┴┬┴─┘
        └──────XOR┘ │   │
                └──XOR──┘ (taps == 7, 5, 4)
    """
    taps = [bits - tap for tap in taps]
    r = seed & (1 << bits) - 1
    while(1):        
        tap_bits = [(r >> tap) & 1 for tap in taps]        
        bit = reduce(lambda x, y : x ^ y, tap_bits)
        yield r & 1
        r &= (1 << bits) - 1
        r = (r >> 1) | (bit << (bits - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that seed is a list of ints rather than a string (or convert it if it is not) then the following should do what you want with a bit more elegance:

```
def lfsr(seed, taps) :
  while True:
    nxt = sum([ seed[x] for x in taps]) % 2
    yield nxt
    seed = ([nxt] + seed)[:max(taps)+1]
```

Example :

```
for x in lfsr([1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,5,6]) :
  print x
```

Comment: this is really interesting to me, still for some reason i cant get it to run. can you show an example of its usage? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
list_init=[1,0,1,1]
list_coeff=[1,1,0,0]
out=[]
for i in range(15):
    list_init.append(sum([list_init[i]*list_coeff[i] for i in range(len(list_init))])%2)
    out.append(list_init.pop(0))
print(out)

#https://www.rocq.inria.fr/secret/Anne.Canteaut/encyclopedia.pdf
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why. Simply posting code is usually not a good answer on SO

Comment: my list_init its what the pdf of anne calls stages, my list_coeff its what in the pdf its called feedback coeff of the lfsr and the results are stored in a new list out, in particular this has the coeff and stages of the example given in the pdf cheers ciao :)

Answer (score 0):

This class provides an easy of use LFSR generator object

```
import numpy as np

class lfsr:
    
    def __init__(self, seed=1, nbits=8, taps=(0,1, 5, 6)): # different taps may not work well. I suggest looking for a standard configuration
        self.seed0 =seed
        self.seed = seed
        self.nbits = nbits
        self.bmask = (2**nbits)-1
        self.taps = taps

        
    def next_rnd(self):
        b_in = 0
        for t in self.taps:
            o = 2**t                                                
            b_in ^= (o&self.seed)>>t                                         
        
        self.seed =(self.seed >> 1) | (b_in << (self.nbits-1))
        self.seed = self.seed & self.bmask          
        return self.seed
        
        
    def print_s(self):
        print(self.seed)        
              
        
    def get_rnd_array(self, seed=None):
        self.seed = seed if seed is not None else self.seed        
        arr = np.zeros((2**self.nbits))      
        for i in range(2**self.nbits):
            arr[i] = self.next_rnd()
            
        return arr

    def get_double_rnd_array_circular(self, seed=None): # ref.: Compact and Accurate Stochastic Circuits with Shared Random Number Sources
        k = int(self.nbits/2)
        self.seed = seed if seed is not None else self.seed        
        arr0 = np.zeros((2**self.nbits)) 
        arr1 = np.zeros((2**self.nbits)) 
        
        for i in range(2**self.nbits):
            rnd = self.next_rnd()            
            arr0[i] = rnd                         
            rnd_p0 = rnd >> k            
            rnd_p1 = (rnd & (2**k-1)) << k                      
            rnd_p2 = rnd_p1 | rnd_p0                    
            arr1[i] = rnd_p2            
        return arr0, arr1
    
    
l = lfsr(1, 4, (0,1))


print(l.get_rnd_array(11))
print(l.get_double_rnd_array_circular(11))
```