# Securing database keys for client-side processing

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a tree of information which is sent to the client in a JSON object. In that object, I don't want to have raw IDs which are coming from the database. I thought of making a hash of the id and a field in the object (title, for example) or a salt, but I'm worried that this might have a serious effect on processing overhead.

```
SELECT * FROM `things` where md5(concat(id,'some salt')) = md5('1some salt');
```

Is there a standard practice for obscuring IDs in this kind of situation?

Comment: So you do not trust the script you are writing with the data in your database?

Comment: If you do not trust the bridge between the web and db servers then using the suggested method will be sending the salt through the bridge to confirm information - sending a salt through the bridge you may as well use plain text to search by id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design a sequential hash-like function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804100/how-to-design-a-sequential-hash-like-function)

Comment: @Quentin, I'm looking for technique - thinking about designing a sequential hash function, I would guess, comes after.

Comment: @ChrisK, I don't want easily guessable and hackable ids being sent to the wider world. I trust the scripts and am validating the data at entry and exit, but don't trust someone with malicious intent ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options for you:

1) You pre-hash every id and store it with the raw id in your database. This may or may not be a good idea depending on your db size and size constraints.

2) Write a simple hash function yourself! I could suggest you something simple if you have no ideas. Just because it's simple doesn't mean it's no good, so long as only you know how it works! I am assuming that the function is not being de-hashed on the client end. Personally, I prefer having processing functions (like hash functions) managed on the server-side code end rather than the db end, because I like to keep MySQL as free as possible to return data with the minimum possible latency.

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to use the php session data to store the list of id#'s sent to the client, with the hash id#s.

This will mean that there will be unique hash's sent out every time which is untraceable the next time it loads up.

The hash ids can be setup however you think (md5 with salt will work in this case, but anything simple will do) and store them in an array in the session.

Try to avoid doing so in the database if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new column with the values of `md5(concat(id,'some salt'))` and calculate it before making the select statement to save calulation overhead.