# How do I stop a user from accessing different ID's by changing url?

Tags: php, mysql

quick question, on my php website, a user is presented with a list based on his user_id, from this list he can select a user which presents him with the following link in the browser:

```
www.examplel.com/users/edituser/7
```

Now if my user changes the 7 in to a 6, he is able to view and edit the data of another user.

How can i prevent this from happening

Comment: Add a database column or better yet a posts table where post ids are linked to user id and check this in your code.

Comment: Do you save some user information in a session? is there a way that your code can identify the user without the url?

Comment: Remove the ID from the URL and automatically load the current user (from a session) on just `/users/edituser`. When the data is saved, save it on the user id in the session as well.

Comment: Thank you guys, Magnus I will try the solution you presented

Answer (score 2):

This is basic security fundamentals, specifically called Authorization.

It seems you have a login system already so all you have to do is lookup the user's setting when they load a URL, then only allow them to load the page if they do have access. There are infinite ways you can actually implement that in code but usually some kind of roles or claims system is used.

Some examples:

- If the user can only edit their own profile, check if the user ID in the url matches their own user ID and only allow if it matches.
- If the user is an admin that can edit any profiles, lookup the user record in the database and check for a setting called IsAdmin, then only load the page if it's their own user ID or if they are an admin.

How you store the access rules that a user has is completely up to you. It can be some extra columns in the database row for that user or it can be several tables for complicated permissions. It depends on what your app needs. Do not store authorization settings in a browser cookie, that should only be an encrypted version of the user ID that you use to lookup everything else on the server when loading the pages.

Comment: 'd be nice if you add some examples

Comment: Thanks for pointing out there are infinite ways to do it and not even name one.

Comment: He didn't name any because you have already done it. You have enough info to present a user with a page containing links the user is allowed to use. So on the edituser page you should be able to use a similar technique to determine if the logged in user has access to the page they are attempting to visit.

Comment: @MarcoMancarne there are no specific ways to do it, basically you check to see who is logged in, then lookup what they have access to in your database, then only load the page if they have access. Infinite ways to actually code that depending on your app. Regardless I updated the answer to add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the ID on the URL means you are using a GET request as a mean of exchanging information between pages/PHP classes. If you wish to pass an information like an ID of a user without allowing him to modify, you should use a **$_POST** or a **$_SESSION** to pass your variables.

In this case, as you have a logged-in user, the **$_SESSION** would be more adequate to you, and you would be able to store a lot of information, and pull the data from your **$_SESSION** array instead of a URL. You could do it like this in case of success in your login method to store a user ID:

```
session_start();
echo 'Bem vindo à página #1';
$_SESSION['userId'] = '7'; //instead of 7 here, it would be the value corresponding to that user id
```

You can find more information in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: Just using POST doesn't make it even close to secure. I can easily make a page that posts what ever ID I want to that page and keep editing anyone's data

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure the logged in user has permission to view the page. So whatever code you are using to provide a list of pages for the user needs to be tweaked slightly and placed at the top of the edituser page. Then if someoen tries to edit a user they aren't supposed to, you can send them to an "error" page or to another page that they do have access to like the list of users.

Answer (score -1):

As much i understand, You can avoid this by using below solutions:

1) Maintain the session with login/logout mechanism . If any user login than only this URL should accessible for particular user. With the session this URL is not accessible for outside person.

2) If its very crucial info like unique id, member id or client id etc. So i would like to suggest don't use as GET parameter. Go with POST.

3) If you really want to go this way only. You can go some encryption methods like (base 64, url encode etc.) and also you can use salt. Please refer this [How to encrypt the $_GET data in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447536/how-to-encrypt-the-get-data-in-php)

Comment: Point 1 works, but point 2 and 3 doesn't help at all if someone really wants to edit someone else data. urlencode an integer won't do anything (and isn't even an encryption) and base64 is not even close to secure.

Comment: 1) Yup agreed, With POST data and url encode , base 64 encoding, its not giving strong encryption but it will prevent from normal human eye. 

2) With salf encryption and as i mention link in 2nd point you can do strong encryption which not easy to decrypt.

Comment: Salt won't help with a base64 encoding (again, encoding, not encryption). Anyone can decrypt a base64 string, no matter what it contains. Don't try to roll your own security solutions. That's how people keeps getting hacked. The _only_ solution in your answer that could be secure is the first one.

Comment: sorry for confusion mangnus. Base64 and url encoding is encode meachnism, we cannot use salt with this. But you can use that encryption which mention in link. For example this is your link www.examplel.com/users/edituser/7 so your '7' will only encrypt not whole URL. So your URL will like www.examplel.com/users/edituser/"encrypted data" OR www.examplel.com/users/edituser?clientid="encrypted data". On server side you can simply decrypt your ID. Its hard to crack.

Comment: You should check that link you posted. They don't tell you how, only a link to some external library/source. and that link is dead (404). That answer is actually a perfect example of why link-only answers are bad.